# Store and retrieve .yml file from SQL Server using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, opencv, yaml

My problem is that I have a Python script that creates a machine learning model for facial recognition (cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer) which I'm storing as `.yaml` format on my localhost(roughly 900KB to 1MB in size). I intend to store it on an SQL Server in a table along with a model-ID and retrieve the model from an SQL query using the model-ID.

```
def store_model(file,model_id):
    #file is of type cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer
    #code to store file and model_id in table

del retrieve_model(model_id):
    #code to return model pertaining to model_id
    return file
```

I need help with the queries to create the tables, specifically with what data type to store the model in and with completing the above functions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yaml (.yml) files are text, so you can store them simply as `NVARCHAR(max)`.

This should support up to ~2GB size.